# Running C++ .exe program from Java has no output, nor receives input

Tags: java, c++, processbuilder

This must be something very specific, because I've tried all known ways already described in several places.

I have MinGW-compiled C++ program that starts with:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        cout << "Sposób użycia: <1> <2>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

In command line it works fine - gets input, gives output, allows pipe redirects.

In Java I've tried using Runtime#exec(), then switched to ProcessBuilder, but neither work. Process#getInputStream() always gives me nothing when I run (or anything similar):

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("compiledCPP.exe");
    Process p = pb.start();
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    int value = -1;
    while ((value = is.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.print((char) value);
    }
    p.waitFor();
```

It should at least give me message written in C++ file in 1st piece of code.

How do I do this?

**EDIT: Unsolvable?**

After trying every possible combination and reading about similar in/out/err-stream-related stuff happening between different compilation units (C++ vs Windows, or 64bit/32bit), I am pretty sure this issue is related to some kind of incompatibility of mingw-generated .exe file against java running on windows. Other than that - same setup apparently works on fully POSIX setup.

If anyone ever finds how to fix it - I'll be glad to hear it (mind that issue is about win/mingw/java8/c++).

Comment: Does this happen only with this program or any program that you run from Java doesn't give an output. I would guess that this is some problem with Java if the program works correctly in the command line. (and being so simple as it is) The only thing that may cause problems in the C++ program is `return -1;`. Maybe try to change it to `return 0;` and see if it does any difference.

Comment: Using "cmd" as command gives me proper output to console (eclipse). Also note that is works without pb.inheritIO();
This must be something specific about C++ exe files. Do they have some special property? I think that they write to PIPES by default, but already tried that approach with actual pipes (">") and java ones (processBuilder.redirectOutput(...) - with all possible options (PIPE, INHERIT, File). Nothing works. Finally - compiled with "return 0" - also nothing.

Comment: Could try `p.waitFor()` right after `pb.start()`. idk, you might be reading the output before it's written.

Comment: I've compiled your Java code (on Linux) and it prints result from simple 'Hello World!' written in C++. It works too if I move `p.waitFor();` before the while loop.

Comment: Here is an idea. Maybe you just catch exceptions and ignore them. If this code throws any, it would seem like the program just doesn't show any output.

Answer (score 0):

May it be that you have to enable output redirection first? 
[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput--).

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cpp.exe");
pb.inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
This would work then, but it doesn't. I tried what you proposed.

Comment: I see this uses the INHERIT type. Have you tried PIPE as well? 
Try using pb.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);

Comment: Indeed. See comment under original post.

Comment: My last guess is to try buffered reading:      
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }

Comment: Also tried that (there was late-edit in main post).
I've even created ever-simple helloWord.exe - it also doesn't write. :C